# The tale of the fabulous rebus

Tags: rebus

A fairytale rebus with a not-at-all-fairytale solution:

```
      ...FAIRY  ...WOLF  ...DUCKLING
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is

> The good, the bad, and the ugly.